# Altium Polygon Pour automatically assign net

Tags: altium

I recently started extensively working with polygon pours. It's not my first time using them, but at the moment i'm doing whole pcb's with them, mainly for thermal reasons.

Whenever i place a pour, it doesn't have a net by default. After placing i have to set the net in the properties manually. Is there a way to automatically assign the pour to a net?
Just like when you start a trace on a pad, the trace is in the same net as the pad.

Comment: "No" is too short to be an answer... but assigning a net is just 2 clicks after you finished drawing the polygon either way.

Comment: Not automatic, but you can press TAB (p g<TAB>) and select the net from the drop-down list in the properties. That way it pours properly when you define the polygon.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany And usually even quicker is to (after you finished creating the polygon) click the pipette icon and an object with the net you want to assign.

Answer (score 0):

When drawing the polygon borders you cannot already define which network to connect it to. It is usually required to do this by hand because there are often objects close to each other that belong to different networks, but if the polygon placement commences at the same location as an existing object that is already connected to a Net, then the Net property of the new object is automatically assigned to that Net.

You can refer to this [Altium guide](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-polygon-pour-properties?version=18.1) where this is mentioned.

Comment: Why refer to a behavior of the software that existed 5 versions ago? At least for the last 3 versions this automatic assignment doesn't exist any more.

Comment: @asdfex Thanks. You're right, unfortunately I only just noticed the reference to an old version of Altium, thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty good success just now. I was copying a certain shape in a repeating pattern. I drew it once, copied "from" one of the flooded pads and pasted onto the other pads in the series. I drew the shape in such a way that it each polygon only contacted one net.

When I repoured all (T - G - A hotkey...) they all accepted their new nets.

If it matters: I had already routed all the connections with thin traces before placing the pours, and I was "pour over all objects."